# php preg_match tab separated

Tags: php, preg-match

I need a regular expression to look for the first N chars on an array until a tab or comma separation is found.

array look like:

```
array (
  0 => '001,Foo,Bar',
  1 => '0003,Foo,Bar',
  2 => '3000,Foo,Bar',
  3 => '3333433,Foo,Bar',
)
```

I'm looking for the first N chars, so for instance, pattern to search is **0003**, get array index 1...

What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: forgot to mention, on an array

Comment: @John you should edit your question to include this new information.

Comment: Someone please supply this man with a solution utilizing **strpos** and not regex...

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(.*?)[,\t]/
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Try the regular expression `/^0003,/` together with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
$array = array('001,Foo,Bar', '0003,Foo,Bar', '3000,Foo,Bar', '3333433,Foo,Bar');
$matches = preg_grep('/^0003,/', $array);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This PHP5 code will do a prefix search on the first element, expecting a trailing comma. It's O(n), linear, inefficient, slow, etc. You'll need a better data structure if you want better search speed.

```
<?php
function searchPrefix(array $a, $needle) {
    $expression = '/^' . quotemeta($needle) . ',/';
    $results = array();

    foreach ($a as $k => $v) 
        if (preg_match($expression, $v)) $results[] = $k;

    return $results;
}   

print_r(searchPrefix($a, '0003'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A REGEXP replacement would be: [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Following your edit:

Use [trim()](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), after searching for a comma with strpos() and retrieving the required string with substr().

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_split` on the string

```
$length=10;
foreach($arr as $string) {
  list($until_tab,$rest)=preg_split("/[\t,]+/", $string);
  $match=substr($until_tab, $length);
  echo $match; 
}
```

or

```
array_walk($arr, create_function('&$v', 'list($v,$rest) = preg_split("/[\t,]+/", $string);'); //syntax not checked
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]/siU';

for($i=0;$i<count($yourarray);$i++)
{
   $ids = $yourarray[$i];
  if(preg_match($pattern,$ids))
  {
    $results[$i] =  $yourarray[$i];
  }

}
print_r($results);
```

**this will print**

```
  0 =>  '001',
  1 => '0003',
  2 => '3000',
  3 => '3333433'
```